# Best way to create a custom form as survey question creation?

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom-form, visual-web-part, survey-list

I need to create a custom question creation form as Survey question creation in SharePoint 2013 survey list. In survey list we can create a question, and we ca choose the options type(Radio, multi choice,single line text,etc)like these [image]

I need to create a custom form like that. so please suggest me an idea to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide more details of what you are trying to achieve to get a more precise answer.